# Module is not longer supported on Drupal 8 but requires 8?

Tags: updating

I'm updating a Drupal 8 site that hasn't been touched in about a year (just updated to 8.9.12). One of the module updates is [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token).

The module page reads:

> **Drupal 7.x and 8.x versions**
> No longer supported.

But for the latest version (9.1.0-alpha1), it reads:

> Requires Drupal: ^8 || ^9

So... I'm confused. Is this safe to install on D8? 8 isn't supported, but it requires 8?

---

*Screen shot of Menu Token page:*

[image: menu token page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be fine to install.

**Then why does it say "no longer supported"?**

Drupal 8 is end of life, so it is no longer receiving feature fixes or security patches.  As a result, work on Drupal 8 (but not 9) modules is no longer being done.  So, there is "no support" because "only the Drupal 9 version is supported."

However, the module still works just as well as it did before support ended for Drupal 8-- it's safe to install.

In other words, "not supported" can be interpreted as "please don't file bug reports/feature requests if you are still on Drupal 8."

**What does "requires" mean?**

"Requires" in the **Downloads** section is a hard technical requirement-- you must have one of the listed versions of Drupal to install the module.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal 8 releases have been programmatically marked as unsupported, in the same way it was done for Drupal 6 releases time ago. They are marked as unsupported because, once a Drupal branch is unsupported, no security issue will be handled by the Drupal.org Security Team, for that Drupal branch and any module compatible with that Drupal release.

What reported as *Requires Drupal: ^8 || ^9* isn't the required Drupal versions but, more exactly, the Drupal versions with which the module is compatible. A release that is compatible with Drupal 8 and Drupal 9 is usually necessary to migrate a site to Drupal 9.
That doesn't mean a module that is compatible with Drupal 8 is always safe to be installed on Drupal 8; it could contains a security issue when the module runs on Drupal 8 that nobody discovered. In the case a security issue is reported, it's up to the project maintainers fix it for Drupal 8.

Notice also that, when a release isn't covered by the security advisory policy, security issues could still be reported. What changes is how those security issues are reported: For releases covered by the security advisory policy, users are required not to report them publicly, but report them to the Drupal Security Team, privately; that isn't required for releases not covered by the security advisory policy, which include the alpha, beta, and release candidate releases.
The 9.1.0-alpha1 release shown in the screenshot isn't covered by the security advisory policy, which means that release is secure to be used on Drupal 8 in the same way it's secure to be used on Drupal 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just some clumsy wording. It's the **module's** versions 7.* and 8.* that are no longer supported. The module's version 9.* is supported and would run on core versions 8 and 9.